# Is it possible to put item in one table only if another item exists in another table atomically in DynamoDB?

Tags: rust, amazon-dynamodb

Say I have 2 tables: "tbl1" and "tbl2"

I want to put a number item 10 under "id" in tbl1 depending on if another number item 15 exists under "namespace" in tbl2. And I want to do this atomically in Rust. Is this possible in DynamoDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [TransactWriteItems](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_TransactWriteItems.html) which is available on all SDKs.

You use a [Put](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_TransactWriteItem.html#DDB-Type-TransactWriteItem-Put) to put the item and then you place a [ConditionCheck](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_TransactWriteItem.html#DDB-Type-TransactWriteItem-ConditionCheck) on the item you want to place your condition on.

This allows you to do both in a single ACID compliant transaction.